# Angularjs showing image blob

Tags: javascript, angularjs, httpresponse

I have a method to call APIs and get responses. One api returning an image. Content-Type:application/octet-stream
If I set responseType: "blob", it is working fine.

```
$http({
            url: apiConstants.BASE_URL + 'login',
            method: "POST",
            responseType: "blob",
            data: {
                "Req": req
            },
            headers: {
                'X-Username': aUser,
                'X-Password': aPass,
            },
        }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
               var URL = $window.URL || $window.webkitURL;
               $rootScope.ImageSrc = URL.createObjectURL(data);
        }
```

But I want to remove responseType: "blob" from the request and trying to create the blob in following way

```
$http({
            url: apiConstants.BASE_URL + 'login',
            method: "POST",
            data: {
                "Req": req
            },
            headers: {
                'X-Username': aUser,
                'X-Password': aPass,
            },
        }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
              var blob = new Blob(
                 [data], 
                 {
                    type: 'application/octet-stream'
                 }
              );

              var URL = $window.URL || $window.webkitURL;
              $rootScope.ImageSrc = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        }
```

But image is not showing in the html. this is the html code

```
<img class="img-responsive empImg" id="empImage" data-ng-src="{{ImageSrc}}" />
```

Could you please advise me on this

Comment: Does `$rootScope.ImageSrc` have a heading signature like `data:image/png;base64`?

Comment: Can I ask why? I think the former (and working) method looks more correct

Comment: @IzumiSy I suggest  you look up the documentation for `URL.createObjectURL`

Comment: Also, the `success` method on the `$http` promise has been deprecated and removed in Angular v1.6. You should not be using it

Answer (score -1):

try to put the src like this :

```
<img class="img-responsive empImg" id="empImage" data-ng-src="'data:image/png;base64,'+{{ImageSrc}}" />
```

and instead of png put the type of the image

Comment: didn't work for me :(. in my case also server side returning a png image. any idea?

Comment: After adding data-ng-src="'data:image/png;base64,'+{{ImageSrc}}" it gives me 500 internal server error.

Answer (score -1):

image/png;base64

Set that as your response type.